# Best way to share database between asp.net web app and mobile applicaion?

Tags: android, asp.net, database

I want to use only one database between my web application and mobile application. what technology can help me to do the same other then web services.

Comment: No technologie needed. You only have to decide where your database would reside. It is unclear what you consider to be a web application or a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try firebase database. Its easy to integrate with mobile and web app.